# How to read HUGE clientmqueue in human format?

Tags: linux, unix, sendmail

Clientmqueue is over 18GB and 
ls /var/spool/clientmqueue
is working 5 min already.
I want to see what mail is in the queue. Maybe i can read some in human format?
To see date title who send it and who is receiver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For typical queue try `sendmail -Ac -bp` or `mailq -Ac`
For **HUGE** queue try `sendmail -O QueueSortOrder=none -Ac -bp`

- `-Ac` selects client queue
- `-Am` selects main/MTA queue

You may add `-v` to get even more verbose output.

In case of **HUGE** queue add `-O QueueSortOrder=none` to avoid sorting queue entries.
If `none` does not work then try `filename`.
AFAIK `none` was added in sendmail-8.13.8 and `filename` in sendmail-8.10.

Documentation:
[QueueSortOrder](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/tweaking_config.html#confQUEUE_SORT_ORDER)

Comment: sendmail -Ac -bp
Takes so much time, i did a coffee break - still its working.  I think it trying to show me 18gb of info? :) maybe it can show only 100 last? :)

Comment: 2 hours past - no gain, there is no output from this command. 18gb is to big i think

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten how sendmail can be "sluggish" with HUGE queues. I have added the relevant extra option that may help.

Comment: thanx alot !!! Its worked !