# Does running sendmail commands from the command-line affect the stability/uptime of the sendmail daemon?

Tags: centos, sendmail

CentOS 5.9 | SendMail 8.14.4

Pardon my ignorance but I'm compelled to ask: Does running separate sendmail commands from the command-line (e.g. `sendmail -d##.# -qRfoo.com`) affect the stability/uptime of the sendmail daemon process that's listening for new incoming connections or delivering outbound messages?

It doesn't appear to interfere but I can't help but think that there might be conflicts if I run a separate command that would try to do something with a deferred message while queue runner tried to handle that same message too.

Comment: 1) Add `-v` to get -d results 2) catch stdout and stderr if you plan to run the command fro cron => `sendmail -v -d##.# -qRfoo.com >> .../log.file 2>&1`

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK It should not in typical cases **BUT** there are quite rare very special cases like e.g. [How to read HUGE clientmqueue in human format?](https://serverfault.com/questions/490888/how-to-read-huge-clientmqueue-in-human-format)

BTW You may use `FEATURE(mailertable)` to select dsmtp mailer (deferred smtp) for deliveries to foo.com. It will allow you to use your `sendmail -v -d##.# -qRfoo.com >> .../log.file` even for first delivery attempt.